# Rails: current_user and sessions clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently reviewing sessions and I came across a pretty generic sessions controller I used before:

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
    self.current_user = user
    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end

def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies[:remember_token] = nil
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end


end
```

And I realized that I used current_user in the views many times. ex:

```
<% if current_user == @user %>
    <%= current_user.name %>
<% else %>
    This user is not you.
<% end %>
```

1. However, I don't understand why `current_user` is accessible as if it is an instance variable. Isn't it a method? Why is it that I can treat it the same as `@current_user` and pull out attributes from it like `current_user.name`, `current_user.age`, etc.? I thought that was only possible for instance variables.
2. In the first and second methods `sign_in(user)` and `sign_out`, what does `self` refer to? These are considered class methods right?

Comment: It might help beginners to realize that `current_user.name` is the same as `current_user().name`. It's just a Ruby convention to drop the parentheses from a function call when there are no parameters. This is very different from other languages where a function name without parentheses does not invoke the function, but is instead a reference or pointer to a function (e.g. in JavaScript, `function currentUser(); end; var myFxn = currentUser; var user = myFxn();`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `current_user` is indeed a method defined in `SessionHelper` that just happens to return a reference to its internal instance variable `@current_user`. Such a method is usually referred to as "reader". Because the returned value is a reference to `@current_user`, you can use that value as if it were the actual instance variable, hence `current_user.name`
2. The use of `self` is necessary in the definition of those two methods because without it, ruby will assume that you want to assign to a new local variable called `current_user` inside of the method instead of calling the method `current_user=()` already defined inside the module. In this case `self` refers to the module itself.